# React Mobx Wizard not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I am having an issue with mobX not firing a render. Think of a wizard with next/previous buttons to load steps (other components).
First the code (in TypeScript) -

*(*Note - I changed names and simplified this code to just show the issue, the actual project it quite different)*

WizardStore:

```
export class WizardStore {
    @observable private currentStep = 0;

    @action public getCurrentStep() {
        return this.currentStep;
    }

    @action public goNext() {
        this.currentStep += 1;
    }
}
```

WizardHost Component:

```
@observer @inject('wizardStore')
export default class WizardHost extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {       
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>                    
                <Wizard />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.wizardStore.goNext()}>Next</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Wizard:

```
@observer @inject('wizardStore')
export default class Wizard extends React.Component<IProps, {}>{
    public render() {    
        return <div>{this.props.wizardStore.getCurrentStep()}</div>;            
    }
}
```

Issue: When I click the Next button, the code is fired in the store and the currentStep property IS updating. The Wizard component does not render the change though.

I think the issue is that my button is updating the store property currentStep, but the render in the WizardHost is not directly using the currentStep property. I thought that because the Wizard component uses the store in it's render that it would cause a re-render anytime currentStep was changed, but it does not. Appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to swap the decorators. `@inject('wizardStore') @observer`

Comment: I was getting a warning that said observer needs to go first. I actually got it all working, but I have no idea why. I did restart vsCode, so it might have been something wonky.

Comment: Great that you got it working!
Check the [`Provider` and `inject`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject) documentation: `When using both @inject and @observer, make sure to apply them in the correct order: observer should be the inner decorator, inject the outer. There might be additional decorators in between.`

Comment: I actually did see that first. It's confusing to me what to do. Here is a copy of the warning from index.nodule.js:
"index.module.js:858 Mobx observer: You are trying to use 'observer' on a component that already has 'inject'. Please apply 'observer' before applying 'inject'"

Comment: Yes, exactly. Swap their places to coincide with the documentation and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it all working, but I have no idea why. I did restart vsCode, so it might have been something wonky.